# Howto: Accessing service objects in a storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard

I'm converting a xib based app to use story boards. My app has both view controllers and service level objects. For example, I have an object that manages communications with servers and another object that manages access to the devices photo libraries.

With xib files I could inject proxy objects and wire them up. But with storyboards there is no such option. Nor does it appear that I can access the app delegate from the storyboard or gain access to any objects instantiated by the storyboard. In summary, it appears that the story board is closed off from the app delegate.

There are two approaches I can see, 1 is to instantiate everything in the storyboard and somehow gain access to the objects from outside the storyboard. The second is to be able to  inject objects into the storyboard when it is created.

So far I've not been able to do either of these things. Does anyone know how to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve lodged a feature request with Apple about this. I’m also now using a DI framework called [Objection](http://objection-framework.org) which I’m finding to be very good.